# MongoDb like aggregation pipeline for json objects

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, npm

I am trying to build an aggregation pipeline on list of objects in typescript. The operations include group, sum,min,max etc. My source DB is not MongoDB. Can anyone help me as to how can I efficiently achieve this. Aggregation logic changes based on key which is passed along with list of objects. I am trying to maintain a json config to achieve this but the structure keeps on getting complex which will be difficult to maintain

Example:

```
key:"key_1"
list:[{
source1:"target1",
value:100,
},{
source1:"target1"
value:100
}]
```

Config says group by source1 key and add value project as aggregatedValue

```
result:[{
source1:"target1",
aggregatedValue:200
}]
```